# Display crypto price in a table using django and cryptocompare

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to make a simple webpage in django where I can display the price of some cryptocurrencies. The user stores in the database the name of the crypto and its initial price. Then I want to fill a table with the ticker and the initial price taken from the database and the current price of each crypto taken with cryptocompare.

This is where the problem begin: the value of 'current price' is taken using [cryptocompare](https://pypi.org/project/cryptocompare/), but how can I dynamically display the value of the current price of each crypto in the table? Maybe the problem is easy to solve but I'm really new and I'm stuck, thanks in advance!

If you need more information ask me!

This is how the table in the index look like. I need to fill the last column with the daily price of the crypto

[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class crypto(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    initial_price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

views.py

```
from .models import crypto

def index_view(request):
    chart = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)
    ticker_list = crypto.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'cryptochart/index.html', {'chart': chart, 'ticker_list': ticker_list})
```

and last, in a file called utils.py I wrote the functions to get the price

```
import cryptocompare
#get price of cryptocurrency
def get_crypto_price(cryptocurrency,currency):
    return cryptocompare.get_price(cryptocurrency,currency=currency)[cryptocurrency][currency]

#get fullname of the cryptocurrency
def get_crypto_name(cryptocurrency):
    return cryptocompare.get_coin_list()[cryptocurrency]['FullName']
```

index.html

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <th>Ticker</th>
            <th>Prezzo Iniziale</th>
            <th>Prezzo Giornaliero</th>                
        </tr>
        
        {% if ticker_list %}
        {% for ticker in ticker_list%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ticker.ticker}}</td>
            <td>{{ticker.initial_price}}</td>
            <td>{{???}}</td>
            
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
        {% endif %}
    </table>
```